# Facebook token by direct GET/POST requets

Tags: facebook, rest, facebook-graph-api, oauth-2.0, facebook-access-token

I need to provide Facebook web access without using browser.
I'm using Play Framework for my needs, and send requests to FB API through web service.
I've checked request parameters for HTTP using firebug with disabled javascript, and handling all redirects to save cookies. But when I send filled form with all hidden parameters and cookies it sends redirect to login page, without token.

GET request with app_id and secret for registered web application:

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=xxxxxxxxxx&secret=yyyyyyyyyyyyyyyy&redirect_uri=https://myhost.com&response_type=token
```

It responds with redirect to `https://www.facebook.com/login.php` page with parameters:

```
skip_api_login=1
api_key=xxxx
signed_next=1
next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.1%2Fdialog%2Foauth...
display=page
```

with reload parameter with same data and additional parameter: `_fb_noscript=1`

Further I'm retreiving data from login form and send it with POST request.
But it redirects me again to login page.

I'm filling my requests with same headers as Firefox do with updated mutable parameters from server response:

```
POST /login.php?login_attempt=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.1%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9443%26response_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%26ret%3Dlogin HTTP/1.1

Host: www.facebook.com

User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux i686; rv:31.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/31.0

Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8

Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5

Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate

Referer: https://www.facebook.com/login.php?skip_api_login=1&api_key=xxxxxxxxxxxx&signed_next=1&next=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Fv2.1%2Fdialog%2Foauth%3Fredirect_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9443%26response_type%3Dtoken%26client_id%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%26ret%3Dlogin&cancel_uri=https%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A9443%2F%3Ferror%3Daccess_denied%26error_code%3D200%26error_description%3DPermissions%2Berror%26error_reason%3Duser_denied%23_%3D_&display=page&_fb_noscript=1

Cookie: datr=MnsEVMW8ZS7nkPtR2E4HrKko; reg_fb_ref=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php%3Fskip_api_login%3D1%26api_key%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%26signed_next%3D1%26next%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fv2.1%252Fdialog%252Foauth%253Fredirect_uri%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A9443%2526response_type%253Dtoken%2526client_id%253Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%2526ret%253Dlogin%26cancel_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9443%252F%253Ferror%253Daccess_denied%2526error_code%253D200%2526error_description%253DPermissions%252Berror%2526error_reason%253Duser_denied%2523_%253D_%26display%3Dpage; reg_fb_gate=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.facebook.com%2Flogin.php%3Fskip_api_login%3D1%26api_key%3Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%26signed_next%3D1%26next%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Fwww.facebook.com%252Fv2.1%252Fdialog%252Foauth%253Fredirect_uri%253Dhttps%25253A%25252F%25252Flocalhost%25253A9443%2526response_type%253Dtoken%2526client_id%253Dxxxxxxxxxxxx%2526ret%253Dlogin%26cancel_uri%3Dhttps%253A%252F%252Flocalhost%253A9443%252F%253Ferror%253Daccess_denied%2526error_code%253D200%2526error_description%253DPermissions%252Berror%2526error_reason%253Duser_denied%2523_%253D_%26display%3Dpage; noscript=1

Connection: keep-alive
```

Is there any way to get Facebook access token dirrectly by POST/GET requests without browser?

Comment: You could simulate a browser I guess. But that would be horrible and probably easy to break

Comment: I guess this would violate the Platform Policies, because a User has to give his permission by himself IMHO